# Better way to generate random numbers

Tags: java, loops, random, integer

Some random number generation, was wondering if I could use a loop to generate all these numbers, instead of writing all the integers out. Is there an even better way than that? could I just leave it, as is?

```
    public static int rx1 = 0+(int)(Math.random()*760);
public static int ry1 = 0+(int)(Math.random()*555);
public static int rx2 = 0+(int)(Math.random()*760);
public static int ry2 = 0+(int)(Math.random()*555);
public static int rx3 = 0+(int)(Math.random()*760);
public static int ry3 = 0+(int)(Math.random()*555);
public static int rx4 = 0+(int)(Math.random()*760);
public static int ry4 = 0+(int)(Math.random()*555);
public static int rx5 = 0+(int)(Math.random()*760);
public static int ry5 = 0+(int)(Math.random()*555);
public static int rx6 = 0+(int)(Math.random()*760);
public static int ry6 = 0+(int)(Math.random()*555);
public static int rx7 = 0+(int)(Math.random()*760);
public static int ry7 = 0+(int)(Math.random()*555);
public static int rx8 = 0+(int)(Math.random()*760);
public static int ry8 = 0+(int)(Math.random()*555);
public static int rx9 = 0+(int)(Math.random()*760);
public static int ry9 = 0+(int)(Math.random()*555);
public static int rx10 = 0+(int)(Math.random()*760);
public static int ry10 = 0+(int)(Math.random()*555);
public static int rx11 = 0+(int)(Math.random()*760);
public static int ry11 = 0+(int)(Math.random()*555);
public static int rx12 = 0+(int)(Math.random()*760);
public static int ry12 = 0+(int)(Math.random()*555);
public static int ry13 = 0+(int)(Math.random()*555);
public static int rx13 = 0+(int)(Math.random()*760);
public static int rx14 = 0+(int)(Math.random()*555);
public static int ry14 = 0+(int)(Math.random()*555);
public static int rx15 = 0+(int)(Math.random()*760);
public static int ry15 = 0+(int)(Math.random()*555);

public static int rx16 = 0+(int)(Math.random()*760);
public static int ry16 = 0+(int)(Math.random()*555);
public static int rx17 = 0+(int)(Math.random()*760);
public static int ry17 = 0+(int)(Math.random()*555);
public static int rx18 = 0+(int)(Math.random()*760);
public static int ry18 = 0+(int)(Math.random()*555);
public static int rx19 = 0+(int)(Math.random()*760);
public static int ry19 = 0+(int)(Math.random()*555);
public static int rx20 = 0+(int)(Math.random()*760);
public static int ry21 = 0+(int)(Math.random()*555);
public static int rx21 = 0+(int)(Math.random()*760);
public static int ry22 = 0+(int)(Math.random()*555);
public static int rx22 = 0+(int)(Math.random()*760);
public static int ry23 = 0+(int)(Math.random()*555);
public static int rx23 = 0+(int)(Math.random()*760);
public static int ry24 = 0+(int)(Math.random()*555);
public static int rx24 = 0+(int)(Math.random()*760);
public static int ry25 = 0+(int)(Math.random()*555);
public static int rx25 = 0+(int)(Math.random()*760);
public static int ry26 = 0+(int)(Math.random()*555);
public static int rx27 = 0+(int)(Math.random()*760);
public static int ry28 = 0+(int)(Math.random()*555);
public static int rx28 = 0+(int)(Math.random()*760);
public static int ry29 = 0+(int)(Math.random()*555);
public static int ry30 = 0+(int)(Math.random()*555);
public static int rx30 = 0+(int)(Math.random()*760);
public static int rx31 = 0+(int)(Math.random()*555);
public static int ry31 = 0+(int)(Math.random()*555);
public static int rx32 = 0+(int)(Math.random()*760);
public static int ry32 = 0+(int)(Math.random()*555);
```

Comment: Sure you can leave it as it is. The code does no useful work. If you describe what you want to achieve, we might have better suggestions.

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: Tagged "slick" -- why?

Comment: No, this is the only one way to do it.

Comment: Why do you need these  many random numbers holding these many random variables ?  Are you asking some random question to some random folks here ?

Comment: He gets random answers, too. Oh sigh. That´s the way it must be I guess.

Comment: For that many random numbers, you should use [Random](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Random.html) instead of [Math.Random()](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/lang/Math.java.html)

Answer (score 4):

Just put them in two arrays:

```
public static int[] x = new int[32];
public static int[] y = new int[32];

for(int i = 0; i < 32; i++)
{
    x[i] = (int)(Math.random()*760);
    y[i] = (int)(Math.random()*555);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use an Array for the same. Here is the sample program

```
package com.stackoverflow.test;

public class RandomCheck {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        int[] tempArray = new int[64];

        for (int i = 0; i < 64; i++) {
            if (i % 2 == 0)
                tempArray[i] = (int) (Math.random() * 760);
            else
                tempArray[i] = (int) (Math.random() * 555);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 64; i++) {
            System.out.print(tempArray[i] + " , ");
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: could you explain why there is 'if' and 'else' statements?

Comment: `if else` block is there to identify which multiplier to use.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `for(;;)` loop along with `ArrayList`. It is not clear from the question if you want fixed amount of those numbers.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.lang.Math;
public class Main{

    public static void main(String args[]){
        int n = 32; // No of random numbers requried for x and y
        ArrayList<Integer> randomNumbersListX = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        ArrayList<Integer> randomNumbersListY = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for(int i=1; i<=n ; i++){
             randomNumbersListX.add((int)(Math.random()*760));
             randomNumbersListY.add((int)(Math.random()*555));
        }
         for(int i=0; i<randomNumbersListX.size() ; i++){
            System.out.println("rx"+(i+1)+" "+randomNumbersListX.get(i));
            System.out.println("ry"+(i+1)+" "+randomNumbersListY.get(i));
        }
    }
}
```

In order to have variable multiplied instead of 1000 you can use another `Math.random()` multiplied by 1000. So `randomNumbersList.add((int)Math.random()*math.random()*1000);` will be the solution.

Please have a look at this [Ideone snippet](http://ideone.com/9jlf78)

Comment: Thanks, I've never seen it done like that before. Might try it

Comment: how do I extract values form this list?

Comment: to extract the values you can use another for loop.I will modify the code.

Answer (score 0):

This would be an approach:

```
public static final int RX_SIZE = 32;
public static final int RY_SIZE = 32;
public static int rx[] = new int[RX_SIZE];
public static int ry[] = new int[RY_SIZE];

static {
    for(int i = 0; i < RX_SIZE; i++) {
        rx[i] = 0+(int)(Math.random()*760);
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < RY_SIZE; i++) {
        ry[i] = 0+(int)(Math.random()*555);
    }
}
```

However it will depend on your specific needs.

Comment: Thank you for answering, this has helped a lot.

Comment: Try to learn how to make code blocks. I edited your answer to the standard way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Commons Math for this as described [here](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/userguide/random.html)

Example, the following will generate a random sequence of 50 long integers between 1 and 1,000,000, using the current time in milliseconds as the seed for the JDK PRNG:

```
RandomData randomData = new RandomDataImpl(); 
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
    value = randomData.nextLong(1, 1000000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We can simply use the random() of java and do it as:

public static int[] x = new int[32];

public static int[] y = new int[32];

for(int i = 0; i < 32; i++)

{

x[i] = (int)(Math.random()*760);

```
y[i] = (int)(Math.random()*555);
```

}

for more information about Math.random() one can follow the link http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_random.asp
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/41336409(v=vs.94).aspx